# How to customise height of card on Laravel Nova dashboard?

Tags: laravel-nova

There is a `->width()` option for [cards](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/metrics/registering-metrics.html#metric-sizes). How can the height be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Nova does not provide a `->height()` method, when you generate a Nova card it creates `resources/js/components/Card.vue` automatically ([see Nova card documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization/cards.html#assets))

The Card.vue file allows you to modify the Vue template for the card element. Since [Nova uses the Tailwind CSS framework](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization/frontend.html#css), you should be able to use the [Height classes of Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height/) inside Card.vue.

Answer (score 2):

As of now you can only adjust the width of the Card from the Card's php file using the `->width()` method.

When you set the card width to `1/2` contents from the card seems to overflow. I solved the issue by adding the class `h-auto` to the `<card>` inside the `Card.vue`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this to my nova theme:

```
.card-panel {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Solution originally posted here:

https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1014#issuecomment-451355417